# Extract Text From Bill Image In Android Studio

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I want to extract text from bill image and want some values like address, location etc .
I want this in android java
Anyone here who guide step by step??

Comment: Buddy, Google these types of things , StackOverflow is for helping debug codes etc. not for  asking questions like this, Start googling and then post again if you are stuck somewhere,

Comment: The question you are asking is too broad to answer here.please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)